# Getting the wrong output for exercism triangle problem

Tags: python, boolean

My code words for isosceles triangle and scalene but the test is kind of contradicting itself I think because my values for this input are right, but it is supposed to be the opposite? Same with scalene.

```
def equilateral(sides):
    x = False
    if sides[0] <= 0 or sides[1] <= 0 or sides[2] <= 0:
        x = False
    elif sides[0] == sides[1] and sides[1] == sides[2]:
        x = True
    else: x = False
    return x


def isosceles(sides):
    x = False
    if sides[0] <= 0 or sides[1] <= 0 or sides[2] <= 0:
        x = False
    elif sides[0] == sides[1] or sides[1] == sides[2] or sides[0] == sides[2]:
        x = True
    else: x = False
    return x


def scalene(sides):
    x = False
    if sides[0] <= 0 or sides[1] <= 0 or sides[2] <= 0:
        x = False
    elif sides[0] == sides[1] or sides[1] == sides[2] or sides[0] == sides[2]:
        x = False
    else: x = True
    return x
```

This is pictures of what the website is saying the output should be.

[!First two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOL6c.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOL6c.png)
[!Last two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcVBd.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcVBd.png)

Comment: The key words in the message are "triangle inequality". I suggest you google this to understand what it means. Hint: it is impossible to make a triangle with sides of length 1, 1, and 3. You need to account for this.

Comment: Also, read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: Indeed, the `inequality` part refers to the triangular inequality, that you forgot to test. By the way, since you set x to False by default in your functions, you only need to test the conditions that make it True,